# Custom Format Number TypeScript Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to format numeric values ​​as follows:
If a number has no decimal places consider the value.
If you have any decimal place format with 4 digits after the "," or "."

Examples:

> **Do nothing**
>   40
>   50
>
> **Leave as follows**
>   4.4        | 4,40000
>   7.1        | 7.10000
>   100.1    | 100.10000
>   1000.2 | 1000.20000

I tried to create an @Pipe But it didn't work out
Follows the code I tried to implement

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'

@Pipe({
  name: 'bigInteger'
})
export class BigInteger extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const format = args[0] ? '1' : '1.4-4';
    let result;
    result = super.transform(value, format).toString().replace(",",".");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<td class="text-center">{{valueOrder | bigInteger: valueOrder > 100}}</td>
```

What is the best solution to my problem?

Comment: What is not working:  Is your transform function not getting called? Or is the function getting called, but the result is not formatted as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `toFixed()` method to do what you need here.

```js
let value = 1.2;

value = value.toFixed(5); // 5 is the number of digits after the decimal
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the number pipe:

```
  <p *ngIf="num % 1 !== 0" >{{num | number:'1.4-4'}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="num % 1 === 0">{{mum | number:'1.0-4'}}</p>
```

And check whether or not the number has a decimal values and display based on the format desired. 
Or with a nice `ng-template` and the **`if else`** touch

```
<div>
    <p *ngIf="num%1!== 0; else noDecimals" >{{num | number:'1.4-4'}}</p>
    <ng-template #noDecimals >decimals<p>{{num }}</p></ng-template>
  </div>
```

**[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poq5gz-nwad4g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdecimal-format.html)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append **0000** in coma values also, it is necessary that the **type** of your values should be of **string**, because without **string** values you cannot append **0000** in the values.

```js
// my array with the numeric values in string format
let arr=["10", "20", "5.2", "6,7"];

// function which check the value and append 0000
function letsCheckAndChange(arr) {
 arr.map((value, index) =>{ 
   if(value.includes(",")) { // to check the coma
     arr[index] = value + "0000"
    } else {
     if(parseInt(value) % 2 != 0) {
       arr[index] = value.toString() + "0000";
      }
    }
  })
}

letsCheckAndChange(arr);

document.write(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I resolved as way

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberPipe'
})
export class DecimalNumberPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any {
    let result;
    if(value % 1 !== 0) {
     result = value.toFixed(4);
    } else if(value % 1 === 0){
      result = value;
    }
   return result;
  }

}
```